# Firefox 78.0.1 does not connect to Django development server running at localhost:8000

Tags: firefox, localhost

Firefox was working ok to browse localhost:8000 on a development machine running Django development server. However, it suddenly stops working (perhaps after a nightly update). The Django server is running fine at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` but when trying to browse `http://localhost:8000/` it just shows the following page:

[image]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I just checked and the Firefox version shows 78.0.1, Release date July 1, 2020. That's the reason I think Firefox has updated and override the settings that allowed the connection to localhost.

**UPDATE 2**: I've installed Epiphany browser and it works. So, the problem is definitely on Firefox side.

**UPDATE 3**: The `curl -v localhost:8000` outputs:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 Found
< Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 07:03:44 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.12
< Vary: Cookie
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /accounts/login/?next=/
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

**UPDATE 4**: The `curl -6v localhost:8000` outputs:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8000/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

Comment: Does `localhost` points to 127.0.0.1? What do you get when you `ping localhost:8000`? What is the output of `cat /etc/hosts`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, localhost is bound to 127.0.0.1. I don´t know what's the idea to ping localhost:8000. There is a web server listening there. I think is more a problem of Firefox blocking requests to localhost now.

Comment: You can try re-installing firefox `sudo apt install --reinstall firefox`

Comment: What does `curl -v localhost:8000` say? Does it work?

Comment: Hi @Ginnungagap, thanks. Please see the UPDATE 3 I've just added to the post.

Comment: How about `curl -6v localhost:8000`?

Comment: @Ginnungagap, please check UPDATE 4 on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is listening on localhost but as an IPv4 only service, while localhost has both an IPv4 address (127.0.0.1) and an IPv6 address (::1) in your (and most everyone else's) `/etc/hosts`.

When you try to connect to http://localhost:8000, Firefox resolves localhost to both, and picks one to try and connect to, **it does not try them all**.

You can solve the issue by explicitly going to 127.0.0.1, or, and since it's 2020 I'd favor this one, by making your app IPv6 aware.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Pointing Firefox to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ didn't help neither. I still get the same page.

Comment: Huh, does your Firefox have a proxy configured? (about:preferences, General, Connection settings)

Comment: When you say you get the same page, I suppose the "can't establish a connection <...>" does change the server address?

Comment: Hi @Ginnungagap, I think this is really a bug in Firefox. I was trying once more after n-times to fiddle with `about:config` option `network.dns.disableIPv6`. I first reset to factory settings and set the value of that setting to `true` . Closed Firefox and re-opened it again. Now, the application at `localhost:8000` started to work. I went to `about:config` settings and the `network.dns.disableIPv6` setting is set to `false`. Very strange. But, now it seems to be working. Let's see for how long. Thanks for your support and patience!!

Comment: I highly doubt that's a bug in Firefox, I wonder if it's not a faulty redirection by your app from 127.0.0.1 to localhost (which could bite you on the ass in production depending on how its setup). Firefox has general DNS caching as well as systems to avoid DNS rebinding attacks so I'm not sure `network.dns.disableIPv6` takes effect without a restart of Firefox.